# How can i select data and get last balance per id?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

i want to select all data from `tbl_item_code` and get last balance form `tbl_lines_code`

tbl_item_code

[image: tbl_item_code]

tbl_lines_code
[image]

this my sql.

```
select i.*,l.balance,last(l.date) 
from tbl_item_code i
left join tbl_lines_code l on i.id = l.id
order by i.id ASC
```

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

**Table similar to yours**

```
create table tbl_item_code (
  id int, 
  item_code varchar(10),
  description varchar(10)
);
insert into tbl_item_code values
(1, 'one', 'one'),
(2, 'two', 'two'),
(3, 'three', 'three');
```

**Lines code table**

```
create table tbl_lines_code (
  id_lines_code int,
  id int,
  dt date,
  balance int
);
insert into tbl_lines_code values
(1, 1, '2010-01-01', 100),
(2, 1, '2015-01-01', 200),
(3, 3, '2010-01-01', 500),
(4, 3, '2015-01-01', 600);
```

**Query**

```
select ic.id, ic.item_code, ic.description, maxdt.maxdt, lc.balance
from tbl_item_code ic
left join (
  tbl_lines_code lc
  inner join (
    select id, max(dt) maxdt from tbl_lines_code group by id
  ) maxdt
    on lc.id = maxdt.id
    and lc.dt = maxdt.maxdt
) on ic.id = lc.id
```

**Result**

```
| id | item_code | description |                     maxdt | balance |
|----|-----------|-------------|---------------------------|---------|
|  1 |       one |         one | January, 01 2015 00:00:00 |     200 |
|  3 |     three |       three | January, 01 2015 00:00:00 |     600 |
|  2 |       two |         two |                    (null) |  (null) |
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08c56/7

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to try to get the last of a field you have to group by and thus can not use the *. Try this:

```
Select i.id_lines_code, i.id, i.no_doc, i.receive, i.issue, i.balance, i.ref,
from tbl_item_code i, Last(l.date) as Last_Updated
left join tbl_lines_code l on i.id = l.id
Group by i.id_lines_code, i.id, i.no_doc, i.receive, i.issue, i.balance, i.ref,
from tbl_item_code i
Order by i.id ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by left join twice and comparing the date.

```
select i.*, maxl.balance, maxl.date
from tbl_item_code i
left join tbl_lines_code maxl on i.id = maxl.id
left join tbl_lines_code l on i.id = l.id on max1.date < l.date
order by i.id asc
```